# How to select top n rows from a datatable/dataview in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

How to the select top n rows from a datatable/dataview in ASP.NET? Currently I am using the following code, passing the table and number of rows to get the records. Is there a better way?

```
public DataTable  SelectTopDataRow(DataTable dt, int count)
{
     DataTable dtn = dt.Clone();
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
         dtn.ImportRow(dt.Rows[i]);
     }

     return dtn;
}
```

Comment: Are you still looking for a satisfactory answer for your query? Otherwise, you may indicate the one that meets your expectation.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In framework 3.5, `dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(n)`

Otherwise the way you mentioned

Comment: This still fetch all data from the database. Limiting no of rows in the query can improve performance while avoiding un-necessary loading of data and memory usage.

Answer (score 36):

I just used Midhat's answer but appended `CopyToDataTable()` on the end.

The code below is an extension to the answer that I used to quickly enable some paging.

```
int pageNum = 1;
int pageSize = 25;

DataTable dtPage = dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: If we bind this to a datagridview then , an update action will not work properly.

Answer (score 33):

```
myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Take(5).CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: This solution should avoid processing all the (possibly many) rows in the `DataTable`, correct?

Answer (score 3):

You could modify the query. If you are using SQL Server at the back, you can use `Select top n` query for such need. The current implements fetch the whole data from database. Selecting only the required number of rows will give you a performance boost as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataTable TopDataRow(DataTable dt, int count)
    {
        DataTable dtn = dt.Clone();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (i < count)
            {
                dtn.ImportRow(row);
                i++;
            }
            if (i > count)
                break;
        }
        return dtn;
    }
```

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.

Answer (score 0):

Data view is good Feature of data table . We can filter the data table as per our requirements using data view . Below Functions is After binding data table to list box data source then filter by text box control . ( this condition you can change as per your needs .Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) )

```
Private Sub BindClients()

   okcl = 0

    sql = "Select * from Client Order By cname"        
    Dim dacli As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = sql
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dacli.SelectCommand = cmd
    dacli.SelectCommand.Connection = Me.sqlcn
    Dim dtcli As New DataTable
    dacli.Fill(dtcli)
    dacli.Fill(dataTableClients)
    lstboxc.DataSource = dataTableClients
    lstboxc.DisplayMember = "cname"
    lstboxc.ValueMember = "ccode"
    okcl = 1

    If dtcli.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ccode = dtcli.Rows(0)("ccode")
        Call ClientDispData1()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FilterClients()        

    Dim query As EnumerableRowCollection(Of DataRow) = From dataTableClients In 
    dataTableClients.AsEnumerable() Where dataTableClients.Field(Of String) 
    ("cname").Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) Order By dataTableClients.Field(Of 
    String)("cname") Select dataTableClients

    Dim dataView As DataView = query.AsDataView()
    lstboxc.DataSource = dataView
    lstboxc.DisplayMember = "cname"
    lstboxc.ValueMember = "ccode"
    okcl = 1
    If dataTableClients.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ccode = dataTableClients.Rows(0)("ccode")
        Call ClientDispData1()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the number of rows to be flexible, you can add `row_number` in the SQL.  For SQL server:

`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myOrder) ROW_NUMBER, * FROM myTable`

Then filter the datatable on row_number:

`Dataview dv= new Dataview(dt, "ROW_NUMBER<=100", "", CurrentRows)`