# how to take top 100 rows from a data source asp.net when using session

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I want to get the first 100 records from a `DataSource`. I have tried but
it's not working.

```
 if (p_ForExport) {
            Session(this.gridData_Session) = ds.wsm_View_PurchaseOrderListForExport;
        } else {
            Session(this.gridData_Session) = ds.wsm_View_PurchaseOrderList;
        }
    divgrid.Visible = true;
        gridPOList.DataSource = Session(this.gridData_Session);
    gridPOList.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(100);
     //tried this but it's not working
        gridPOList.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: You could try *gridPOList.DataSource = Session(this.gridData_Session).Take(100);*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [take top 10 or 20 rows from dynamic datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718484/take-top-10-or-20-rows-from-dynamic-datatable)

Comment: @TrungDuong not working !! take is not coming after seesion

Comment: Because session variables are type of object, you must cast it before calling Take (cast it into type of your ds.wsm_View_PurchaseOrderList)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select top n rows from a datatable/dataview in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787458/how-to-select-top-n-rows-from-a-datatable-dataview-in-asp-net)